# alphanumeric formula field

Tags: formula-field

I need to generate a url from multiple fields on a object. This is what I have so far

```
"https://www.companyabc.com/property-details/" + 
SUBSTITUTE(pba__Address_pb__c + " " + pba__City_pb__c + " " + pba__PostalCode_pb__c 
+ " " + pba__StateCode_pb__c + " " + pba__Country_pb__c, 
"(\\D)+(\\d)+[^%$#@&!*()^+_-][^=,<.>/?~`]", "-")
```

It should generate

> https://www.companyabc.com/property-details/1234-Main-St-Los-Angeles-91234-CA-USA

But instead is generating

> https://www.companyabc.com/property-details/1234 Main St Los Angeles 91234 CA USA

Is what I'm trying to achieve possible?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your exact use case, it looks like you're missing the substitute for spaces; add the following to your formula:

```
SUBSTITUTE( (YourFormula) , " ", "-")
```

That should replace the spaces with dashes. You might however want to clean up your formula a little bit, escape parenthesis, brackets and other characters where necessary.

Comment: but what about special characters such has periods? how would I remove all non-alphanumeric characters with dashes?

Comment: Formulas will get very complex and may cross the size limits. An Apex trigger removing the non alpha characters in your fields may be a more solid option here

Comment: I agree. My boss wants a formula field though D: